# Adding Dependency to android studio without internet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an isolated computer(C1) and i want to develope some android app.i have another computer(C2) too can connect to internet. i want to add volley library to my C1. how can i add dependency ? i dont need .jar file. i need .aar files.can i just copy some files from .gradle folder into my C1?

Comment: add it as jar file. Download it on C2, copy to USB flash, copy from USB flash to C1, add as JAR lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your connected computer to download all your dependencies and then copy the `.gradle` and `.m2` folders under home directory `~/` into the home directory of your computer that has no internet connection.

Comment: i dont have .m2.

Answer (score 0):

Download jar from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mcxiaoke.volley/library/1.0.19)

OR

1. Git clone the repository by typing the following at the command line:

> git clone https://github.com/google/volley

2. **Import** the downloaded source into your app project as an Android library module

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @vladyslav-matviienko i found the answer .

1. clone the lib project into your computer

   ```
   git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
   ```
2. download and install apache ant from [here](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgir")!
3. generate volley.jar; go into volley root dir in cmd (using "cd" command) and execute below commands.

   ```
   android update project -p .

   ant jar
   ```

   You can find generated volley.jar in volley bin folder.
4. go to android studio and change android view to project view in the project menu from left panel and just drag you .jar file to *libs* folder  .then right-click and click on compile as library.
   *dont forget to check if you have below code in build.gradle(app level) in the dependency section*

   ```
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

first you should download the library.

for example for picasso library, go to this [address](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.squareup.picasso%3Apicasso) 
select file section , and select the version you want and download all file.
then copy those file in libs folder in android-studio [image: libs]
[image: file section]